# UITableView doesn't show anything

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I wrote an app that it have a UITableView in UIViewController and here is my codes:

```
class CategorySelectViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var melliSubCategories = [String]()
var mazhabiSubCategories = [String]()
var sayerSubCategories = [String]()


@IBOutlet weak var melliButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var sayerButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var mazhabiButton: UIButton!


@IBAction func melliButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    categorySelected = 6
    melliButton.isHighlighted = true
    mazhabiButton.isHighlighted = false
    sayerButton.isHighlighted = false
    categoryTableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func sayerButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    categorySelected = 5
    melliButton.isHighlighted = false
    mazhabiButton.isHighlighted = false
    sayerButton.isHighlighted = true
    categoryTableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func mazhabiButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    categorySelected = 4
    melliButton.isHighlighted = false
    mazhabiButton.isHighlighted = true
    sayerButton.isHighlighted = false
    categoryTableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    categoryTableView.dataSource = self
    categoryTableView.delegate = self
    categoryTableView.register(CategorySelectTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    melliSubCategories = DataBaseManager.shared.subCategories(6)
    mazhabiSubCategories = DataBaseManager.shared.subCategories(4)
    sayerSubCategories = DataBaseManager.shared.subCategories(5)
    print(melliSubCategories)
    print("/////////////////")
    print(mazhabiSubCategories)
    print("/////////////////")
    print(sayerSubCategories)
    print("/////////////////")
}

@IBOutlet weak var categoryTableView: UITableView!


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch categorySelected {
    case 4: //mazhabi
        return mazhabiSubCategories.count
    case 5: //sayer
        return sayerSubCategories.count
    case 6: //melli
        return melliSubCategories.count
    default:
        return melliSubCategories.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CategorySelectTableViewCell
    cell.label?.text = melliSubCategories[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

And I create a class named `CategorySelectTableViewCell` for cells in table view that they have an image and a label.

In code I fill the arrays by database and I want to show them in the table view but the tableview doesn't show anything.

the screenshot : [my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PJSI.png), [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSLuC.png)

Comment: are you use xib for custom cell?

Comment: If you print the count values that you're returning, what do you see?  If you print what you're putting into the label, what do you see?

Comment: @iParesh no I don't use xib, I create custom cell by table view cell

Comment: @PhillipMills all of the prints work fine, and also the count of cells is correct but the cell is empty without any label

Comment: @arash if you dont use xib then why you registerCell? Try print `melliSubCategories[indexPath.row]` in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: @arash the style of you cell is custom?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski print works correctly, I use registerCell because whiteout it app crashes and say `reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: Perhaps cell.label isn't connected to anything visible in your custom cell?

Comment: @JoséNeto yes it's custom

Comment: @arash set identifier in storyboard

Comment: @PhillipMills label is connected, I checked at connection inspector

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski it was already set

Comment: @arash Check whther `cellForRow` is called or not?

Comment: @arash `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CategorySelectTableViewCell` Try this line

Comment: "label is connected" Where? If you are using a xib you should be registering the nib, not the class. If you are using a storyboard you should not be registering at all. And those are the only possibilities.

Comment: @agent_stack cellForRow calls, and your suggestion has error

Comment: @arash You tableview and prototype-cell is created in storyboard ? even your VC is also storyboard?

Comment: @matt you're right, but I don't use xib and I connect the label with CRTL+drag in storyboard, and of course registering is not my problem

Comment: @agent_stack tableview and prototype cell is created in storyboard, what is VC ?

Comment: @arash Viewcontroller in short

Comment: @arash the label is connected to the CategorySelectTableViewCell? And is the tableView connected to you viewController?

Comment: @arash Add your storyboard screenshot and custom cell class. I don't think until then someone cant helps you.

Comment: @agent_stack my vc is also storyboard, how could I attach screenshot ?

Comment: @arash add your screen images here so that we can more precisly what actually you are trying to do. Because you have missing somthg or asking smthg wrng. So here we unable to predict and its better is you can give us your project demo. We modify it and give it back to you.

Comment: @arash have you set tableview delegate and datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

```
cell.label?.text = melliSubCategories[indexPath.row]
```

It is impossible for this to work. For it to work, your custom cell type CategorySelectTableViewCell would need to be in a nib with a `label` outlet. But then that nib is either in a storyboard or a xib file. But you are also saying

```
categoryTableView.register(CategorySelectTableViewCell.self, ...
```

That line *prevents* the cell from coming from the xib or the storyboard. So the outlet cannot work and the cell will remain empty.

Comment: I also thinking about... `cell.label?.text` how it can be. initially i thought he using native cell but then I scroll code and its not native. Not getting what actually he is doing. :/

Comment: if i delete this line app crashes and say `reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'` but I also set the identifier of prototype cell

Comment: But your storyboard is incorrectly configured. Your view controller is not seeing the table view in the storyboard correctly.

Comment: Maybe you should post a screen shot of the storyboard showing the relevant configuration.

Comment: @matt screenshot added

Comment: Thanks. And what does the app look like when you run it?

Comment: picture of demo was added

Comment: Okay, that's good. But it's what I would expect to see _if you register the class_ with `categoryTableView.register(CategorySelectTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`. You _must_ delete that line. That is what my answer tells you.

Comment: Also your screen shots do not prove that this prototype cell has identifier `"Cell"` in the storyboard. But that, of course, is crucial. Plus the prototype cell must be marked as being a CategorySelectTableViewCell.

Answer (score -3):

Please check array count is Zero or not in below numberOfRowsInSection method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

Also, cross-check cell identifier is correct or not.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell : CategorySelectTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CategorySelectTableViewCell
    cell.label?.text = melliSubCategories[indexPath.row]       
    return cell
}
```

Reload tableview in ViewDidLoad method:

> categoryTableView.reloadData()

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    categoryTableView.dataSource = self
    categoryTableView.delegate = self
    categoryTableView.register(CategorySelectTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    melliSubCategories = DataBaseManager.shared.subCategories(6)
    mazhabiSubCategories = DataBaseManager.shared.subCategories(4)
    sayerSubCategories = DataBaseManager.shared.subCategories(5)
    print(melliSubCategories)
    print("/////////////////")
    print(mazhabiSubCategories)
    print("/////////////////")
    print(sayerSubCategories)
    print("/////////////////")
    categoryTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This just repeats the OP's question

Comment: @AshleyMills what's OP ?

Comment: Original Poster. You haven't given an answer - you just repeated his question. He has already clarified the points your raise